# What if use Effigear gear box and Alfine 11 gear hub together?

Tags: hub

What if we use two types of planetary gear hubs together? Like Effigear and Shimano Alfine 11. First on the pedals and second on the back wheel?
Will it increase number of transmissions? Or increase the step variation between transmissions?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You multiply the two ratios you are using by the ratio of the number of teeth on the chainring to the number of teeth on the rear sprocket.  The Effigear lists its maximum range as 9 speeds from 0.853 to 4.  For comparison, my road bike has 50/34 front and 11-32 rear.  My maximum ratio is 50/11 or 4.545 and my minimum is 34/32 or 1.0625.  If you couple the Effigear to 50 front and 44 rear gears you would get a range from slightly lower than mine at the bottom of 0.969 to matching mine at the top.  This is not surprising-they want the Effigear to cover the range most riders want.  If you now install an internally geared hub you just multiply these by the ratio of whatever gear you are in on the hub.  You would get a range of a factor of over 16 from top to bottom.  Many of the gears would be too low or too high to use.